# Apps keep asking for Apple ID info after backup

Tags: itunes, applications, iphone

The last time i connected my iPhone 5 to my laptop and synchronized with iTunes, something weird happened. All of my paid applications keeps asking for my Apple ID and password and entering just closes the application, and if i tried to open an application without internet connection, the app just closes instantly like a crash. i tried to restore but no good. One important note is that the apps were downloaded by a friend of mine using his account, then i made an apple account but i didn't enter my credit card information so i can't buy application using my account. so i am just wondering if this is the problem, the apps were paid by different account and my account doesn't allow purchases, or what do you think ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you answered your own question. Those apps are all associated with your friend's account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say the apps were downloaded under your friend's account, and they are **paid**.

### Paid = **You** pay for it -- not **friend** pays for it.

There is a limitation in iOS preventing this from happening - you will need to know your friend's Apple ID and password to open the app - to prove it was **you** who bought them.

### But why?

Without this limitation, there would be an epidemic of groups of college students using one Apple ID to 'split' the cost of apps, and have them on a lot of different people's devices. This is stealing from both the developer and Apple (Devs get 70% of app sales, Apple gets 30%), and Apple doesn't like to have it's cash stolen. Devs don't either. I'm one of them.